# how to construct possible mutual exclusive fqs in solr

Tags: solr

Totally new to Solr. Could anyone tell me if these statements are correct

```
&fq=(month:"11" OR month:"12") -> those month in 11 or 12
&fq=month:"11" & fq=month:"12" -> same as above

&fq=month:"11" & fq=-month:"12" -> those month in 11 but not in 12, effectively only 11
&fq=(month:"11" OR -month:"12") -> same as above


&fq=-month:"11" & fq=-month:"12" -> those month not in either 11 or 12
&fq=-(month:"11" OR month:"12")  -> same as above

&fq=month:"11" & fq=-month:"11" -> returns 0 since they are mutual exclusive
&fq=(month:"11" OR -month:"11") -> same as above
```

and also will `&fq=(month:"11" OR -month:"11")` slow down performance (by merging result from month:"11" with result of -month:"11") or solr can do some analysis on fqs and merge them before doing the actual query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your all other statements are correct but the following is not.

**&fq=month:"11" & fq=month:"12"** -> All separate fq clauses are treated as AND operations hence, this will not return any results unless month is a multivalued field with documents having both 11 and 12 values.